# Postgres knowing which where column returned positive result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Assuming we have a query like:

```
select * from table where a=1 or b=2 or c=3
```

and the where conditions met are `a=1` and `c=3`

Would it be possible to know in the query (in the output) that `a` and `c` are the columns that matched the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select t.*, a=1 as "a=1", b=2 as "b=2", c=3 as "c=3"
from table t
where a=1 or b=2 or c=3;
```